# Set Jackson JSON serialization for specific type to use toString() using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Using Java 17 I have a `FooBar` type I want serialized to JSON using its `toString()` method. I'm serializing using a Jackson `ObjectMapper` (created via a `JsonMapper.Builder`).

I read that I can use the `@JsonValue` annotation on the `FooBar` class `FooBar.toString()` method. But is there a way to configure the `ObjectMapper` instead, without creating some special factory class specifically for `FooBar`? (I did this years ago but I don't remember if I created a separate factory implementation or what.)

I was expecting (hoping for) something like this:

```java
objectMapperBuilder.serializerFor(FooBar.class, ToStringSerializer.instance());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer` as a custom deserializer for the `FooBar` class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(FooBar.class, new ToStringSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! It's coming back to me now—I had forgotten I needed to put that in a module. Thanks for taking the time to post this.

Comment: I added follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/q/76560273 .