# Set Jackson JSON deserialization for specific type to use static factory method using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Using Java 17 I have a `Bar` type I want serialized to JSON using its `toString()` method. I'm serializing using a Jackson `ObjectMapper` (created via a `JsonMapper.Builder`). I found out from [Set Jackson JSON serialization for specific type to use toString() using ObjectMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76559047) that I can specify a `ToStringSerializer` as a serializer in a `Module`, as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76559162) indicated:

```java
…
module.addSerializer(Bar.class, new ToStringSerializer());
//technically ToStringSerializer.instance would be better, but it's the same idea
…
```

But now how about deserializing `Bar` using a static factory method? Without further context Jackson won't know the type of the string, but if it's deserializing a property of `Foo` e.g. `Foo.bar`, it will know the type should be `Bar`. So is there a way to set up a deserializer that will use a static factory method `Bar.createNewBarInstance` to create a `Bar` when setting `Foo.bar`? Something like this?

```java
…
module.addDeserializer(Bar.class,
    new StaticFactoryDeserializer("createNewBarInstance"));
…
```

Is there some sort of deserializer for static factory methods that gives me that sort of functionality?

Looking at the code from `FromStringDeserializer.Std._deserialize(…)`, I see that known types are simply checked using a `case` and then the static factory methods are explicitly invoked, e.g. `Charset.forName(value)` or `URI.create(value)`. Does that mean there is nothing that would allow `new StaticFactoryDeserializer("forName")` and `new StaticFactoryDeserializer("create")`, etc. to do the same thing? Surely someone has thought of this before.

Comment: What about defining custom deserializer which implementation calls any static method you like?

Comment: That's the whole point of the question—that's what I'm looking for. That's what I'm referring to by `StaticFactoryDeserializer`, where I indicate a static factory method such as `createNewBarInstance`. Is there such a deserializer implementation already? Or are you saying I have to write one?

Comment: Oh, do you mean writing a custom deserializer that is hard-coded to call a single static factory method just for the `Bar` type? But there are so many classes that need that—why create the same boilerplate over and over, if the only difference is knowing the name of the static factory method?

Comment: Then you could write a single generic custom deserializer that takes a function as a constructor parameter and holds it as a field of type `Function<String, T>`. Then instantiate it once per each class like `addDeserializer(Bar.class, new CustomDeserializer<Bar>(SomeClass::stringToBarFunction));`. Hope i've described well enough.

Comment: Yes, using a function like this was my other idea.  But is there a deserializer class like this already?

Comment: I opened a ticket with Jackson databind, [Issue #4004](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/4004).

Comment: You could annotate the `toString` method with the `@JsonValue` annotation. For the second question if you are referring to deduce subtypes based on the presence of properties distinct to a particular subtype there is a deduction system, you can check the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation.